# Dynamic RTD Data Recording to Another Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, range, row, rtd

This code works fine when the data is presented from a range of C4:C7 column however my worksheet is setup with data in a row from C4:K4. I can't get a row instead of a column to work out. Any help? Thanks [image: view pic with issue].

```
Sub RecordData()
Dim Interval As Double
Dim cel As Range, Capture As Range
Interval = 30 'Number of seconds between each recording of data
Set Capture = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C4:K4") 'Capture this row of data
With Worksheets("Sheet2") 'Record the data on this worksheet
    Set cel = .Range("A2") 'First timestamp goes here
    Set cel = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cel.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    cel.Value = Now
    cel.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, Capture.Cells.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(Capture.Value)
End With
NextTime = Now + Interval / 86400
Application.OnTime NextTime, "RecordData"
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need to transpose. Just = Capture.Value.

Comment: @Excelosaurus if you add that as an answer, I'll upvote it :)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the feedback I'm new to VBA. So Capture = Worksheets("Sheet1").C4:K4

Comment: @mjac change `cel.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, Capture.Cells.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(Capture.Value)` to `cel.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, Capture.Cells.Count).Value = Capture.Value`.

Comment: Just figured it out. Wow you guys are good. Thanks for seeing this so fast. Any youtube vids you know of I could watch to help me get better? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transposing `Capture.Value` is the problem; you don't need to do this, since both the destination and source ranges have the same shape.

Suggestion: avoid referring to worksheets by the name they display on their tab in Excel. These names typically change over time and will cause your code to break. For example, `With Worksheets("Sheet2")...` will fail with error 9 "Subscript out of range" as soon as you change Sheet2's name to something else.

You can give a stable, "internal" name to a worksheet, and directly use it in VBA code, as long as said VBA code resides in the same workbook as the worksheet. The worksheet property I am referring to is called `CodeName`. You can set it from the Visual Basic editor by clicking on the worksheet in the Project Explorer, then assigning to the (Name) property in the Properties Window, as shown below, where I've given the CodeName "SourceWs" to a worksheet named "Source Worksheet" as seen from Excel:

[image]

Then, your code could be rewritten as:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RecordData()
    Dim Interval As Double
    Dim cel As Range, Capture As Range
    Dim NextTime As Date

    Interval = 30 'Number of seconds between each recording of data

    Set Capture = SourceWs.Range("C4:K4") 'Capture this row of data

    With DestWs 'Record the data on this worksheet
        Set cel = .Range("A2") 'First timestamp goes here
        Set cel = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cel.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        cel.Value = Now
        cel.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, Capture.Cells.Count).Value = Capture.Value
    End With

    NextTime = Now + Interval / 86400
    Application.OnTime NextTime, "RecordData"
End Sub
```

As for your question about training videos, try googling `excel mvp blog` and you'll find more than you can handle. Have fun.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the help. I forgot about how renaming the tab could affect your code. I'll check out that blog also :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The best way to thank us is to upvote answers that helped you, and mark the accepted answer as such.

Comment: Hi again. I tried to upvote but I do not have enough rep points(says I need 15 only have 11) to do it yet. I accepted the answer though that seem to go through.

Comment: @ Excelosaurus. This code has been working great but I need to modify it. I added a few additional rows of "Real Time Values" that I need to capture. But I can only get the 1st row captured (C4:K4). Any ideas on how to get C5:K5, C6:K6 etc. Thanks

Comment: To copy several rows at a time, say up to row 6, try `Set Capture = SourceWs.Range("C4:K6")` and `cel.Offset(0, 1).Resize(Capture.Rows.Count, Capture.Columns.Count).Value = Capture.Value`. For more help, consider creating a new question.

Comment: @ Excelosaurus. This worked out great. Thanks for your time. Can you help me out on another question located here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54270699/workbook-save-close-re-open-w-timevalue-repeat

Comment: @ Excelosaurus. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55776267/send-email-w-out-outlook-referencing-worksheet-data